# Thumb doubles the image file size

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic

My original images are 420x500/840x1000 and the file size varies around 15-30kb per image. Though when resized by wordpress/woocommerce into a thumb to 340x340(crop) the image size gets to 50kb+.
The resizing happends automatically by Wordpress/woocommerce.

[Link to website](http://brightbuybusiness.se) - I'm using XING, a theme from Themeforest.

The image sizes has been changed in Woocommerce "Image Alternatives" to crop and 340x340px.

```
function gpp_jpeg_quality_callback($arg)
{
return (int)100;
}


add_filter('jpeg_quality', 'gpp_jpeg_quality_callback');
```

Found this code in Functions.php though. Is this the issue?

Comment: Please show us how and where you registered the themes/plugins image sizes. No chance to help you without seeing actual code in an [edit]. If you didn't code it yourself, you'll have to come up with your plugins source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to compress the image. Wordpress offers a filter to set the compression ratio.

```
function my_jpg_compression($args) {
    return 75;
}
add_filter('jpeg_quality', 'my_jpg_compression');
```

> ***NOTE:*** What you are returning is the compression ratio. 70-80% is
>   manageable and you will not notice much reduced image quality. Also,
>   after applying this filter only future image's size can be reduced and
>   not the one which are already uploaded.

**What for already uploaded images?**

You can use some awesome plugins to reduce image size and still keeping manageable quality. One of such a plugin is [WP SmushIt](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/). In fact you can use this plugin for future uploaded images too.